# Are camel endpoints global and shared over several JVMs on the same server?

Tags: java, apache-camel

Lets say a camel context implements a route which consumes from an endpoint (direct://simpleEndpoint), and another java program sends to this endpoint in its main method using a producer template. Will the messages be received on the consumer?

Right now, I'm not able to make this work?
Is there any other way to test by sending dummy messages to an endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

direct only works within the same CamelContext. 
You could use direct-vm to communicate across different CamelContexts but **within** the same JVM.

If you want to communicate across different JVMs you should look at jms or activemq instead.